# c# ZLib.Net decompression

Tags: c#, .net, stream, compression, zlib

I'm trying to decompress a byte array using the `ZLib.Net` library. Unfortunately my function is always returning two bytes only. The compressed array has 1240 bytes. No one of `zlibConst` values does return more than two bytes.

Maybe something is wrong with `ZLib.Net`? (the DLL is taken from here: http://zlibnet.codeplex.com/)

```
byte[] Decompress(byte [] compressed)
{
    byte[] rez = new byte[compressed.Length];

    MemoryStream oInStream = new MemoryStream(compressed);
    ZInputStream oZInstream = new ZInputStream(oInStream, zlibConst.Z_BEST_COMPRESSION);
    MemoryStream oOutStream = new MemoryStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[2000];
    int len;
    while ((len = oZInstream.read(buffer, 0, 2000)) > 0)
    {
        oOutStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    oOutStream.Flush();
    byte[] arrUncompressed = oOutStream.ToArray();
    oZInstream.Close();
    oOutStream.Close();

    return arrUncompressed;
}
```

Comment: What is the content of your 1240 byte input array?  (Have you tried with a smaller input array, containing just "Hello, World!" ?)

Comment: And why on earth are you calling your input array "compressed" when you are proceeding to compress its contents?

Comment: And what does "Base64" have to do with all this?

Comment: Where did you get ZInputStream? I downloaded the library and that class is not available.

Comment: @Mike Nakis the function name is irrelevant. I'm trying to decompress, not to compress.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath, sorry, actually I' using another lib: http://www.componentace.com/zipforge.net_features_list.htm